# Bash Script getting stuck during execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-script

I have a bash script that is reading a `CSV` file , that contains `source IP` address , `destination IP` address and `destination port`.

My script is basically doing 2 tests:

1 Performance
 2 Connectivity.

Under performance test, I am copying files from `source` to `destination` (using `scp`) to calculate the the network IO. After that, copying the same file from one location of Destination server to other location on destination server to calculate Disk I/O.

Under connectivity test I am doing `nc` from `source` to `destination` to check whether `port` is open or not.

**Problem :** Sometime while execution of script, it get stuck at some point and then I have to press `Ctrl+C` to kill that process to continue the further execution.

Here , i am not able to figure it out why it is getting stuck, and even behavior is not consistent , every time it's stuck at different location in the script.

Please help me in resolving this issue. If required I can post my complete script here.

**Update :**

**Observation :** Other thing that i observed , if i don't press Ctrl+C , then script resume automatically after 5 mins.

Part of the actual script , where it is getting stuck.

```
#Connectivity Test
TMP=$(mktemp)
nc -z -v -n $lastDestinationIP $port >\$TMP
if grep -q "succeeded" <<< cat echo \$TMP;then
   echo $x','$lastSourceIP','$lastDestinationIP','$sourceFqdn','$fqdn','$port',Connectivity,NA,NA,NA,Pass,'$(date) | ssh $username@$baseLocation 'cat >> report.txt'
else
  echo $x','$lastSourceIP','$lastDestinationIP','$sourceFqdn','$fqdn','$port',Connectivity,NA,NA,NA,Fail,'$(date) | ssh $username@$baseLocation 'cat >> report.txt'
fi
rm $TMP
fi
exit
ENDSSH
```

**Most of the time it stuck while calling exit.**

Here is the snippet where it stuck most of the time (from the console).

```
21 14:48:16 EDT 2014 | ssh puppet-admin@10.X.X.9 'cat >> report.txt','Fri Mar
> fi
>
> #rm KB_33.txt
> #rm MB_10.txt
> #rm MB_100.txt
> rm -rf dummy
> else
> #Connectivity Test
> nc -z -v -n -w 2 10.X.X.17 1524 >/tmp/tmp.GJ1knZF5Jn
> if grep -q "succeeded" <<< cat echo /tmp/tmp.GJ1knZF5Jn;then
 21 14:48:16 EDT 2014 | ssh puppet-admin@10.X.X.9 'cat >> report.txt','Fri Mar
> else
21 14:48:16 EDT 2014 | ssh puppet-admin@10.X.X.9 'cat >> report.Fail,'Fri Mar
> fi
> fi
> exit
>
```

Comment: You can start your script in debug mode by invoking the `-x` of the shell (valid for bash, I don't know for other shells) : `bash -x <script name>`. You will see more details over what the script is doing when it gets stuck.

Comment: i tried that but it is not helping much

Comment: I don't think the code you pasted is correct at all. Could you please post relevan parts of the script. Also expected output and actual output would help.

Comment: Rather than kill it you can also use `strace` to connect to the running process ID to take a peek inside to see what it's blocking on. `strace -p <PID>`

Comment: So '21 14:48:16 EDT 2014' is supposed to be echoed across the *`|ssh pipe`* to *`cat >>?`* What sends it there, in your *`if/else?`*

Comment: You need to fix your quotes. When date expands it breaks apart the *`"echo"`*. Also you dont need all of that stuff: cat <<HEREDOC >>~/my.file\n $Var1 $Var2 $Var3\nHEREDOC\n ; cat ~/my.file - values of Var1 Var2 Var3

Comment: Youd be better off feeding your ssh commands a separate heredoc a piece and you wouldnt wind up catting for 5 minutes because you wouldnt need so many craxy quotes.

Comment: @mikeserv in the if else I am sending the status either as "Pass" or "Fail".
I didn't understand last 2 comments of yours , can you please put more light on this. I am just a newbie and have written the script for the first time. Please bear with me.

Comment: Ive written this answer before - im trying to find it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the *short and sweet* - a *`heredoc`* is basically a file streamed to a file-descriptor.

Most people don't denote the *`0<<descriptor`* and so you get it on *`<&0 stdin. ssh`* passes *`stdin`* to its invoked process so if you feed it a *`heredoc`* it will pass through the input to the invoked remote shell.

The one very special quality about *`heredocs`* is the difference between a *`\"'quoted`* and *`unquoted heredoc LIMITER.`* So, *`<<'THIS'`* differs from *`<<THIS.`* When you do not quote the *`LIMITER,`* the contents of the here-document are evaluated for *`${shell:+expansion}`.* Once one *`${shell:+expansion}`* pass is completed, there is very little else to distinguish a here-document from any other file fed as *`<~/input`.*

For example:

```
cat <<\QUOTED >~/file
    $(echo "This is ${NOT:-} expanded.")
#END
QUOTED
cat <~/file
> $(echo "This is ${NOT:-} expanded.")
> #END
```

But...

```
cat <<UNQUOTED >~/file
    $(echo "This is ${NOT:-} expanded.")
#END
UNQUOTED
cat <~/file
> This is  expanded.
> #END
```

You keep using the *`bash <<< herestring`* with *`cat.`* I don't know exactly how the *`herestring`* works but I'm willing to bet *`cat's`* already involved. So *`cat` concatenates* its *`<&0stdin`* with its *`stdout>&1`.* That's all it does. So you're unnecessarily complicating *`<<STDIN`* when you *`<<< cat`* it.

This can be a real problem if *`cat`* winds up consuming an input stream which you did not intend it to consume. Run just *`% cat`* at your terminal and it will look like nothing is happening because a terminal's *`stdin`* and *`stdout`* are the same file - your *`$(tty)`.* But when they differ, *`cat` combines* them anyway and that can get pretty messy if you didn't mean it to happen.

It looks to me like some *`\'quotes`* are skipping an expansion when *`$(date)`* is *`$expanded`.* Then possibly the *`: null shell builtin`* is invoked and *`|piped`* to the next *unquoted command* after *`ssh`* which would be *`cat >> report.fail`* which should generate nothing at all in that file. So *`cat`* is *`>>appending /dev/null`* to *`report.fail`,* for as long as it can stand it, I guess. Or, more likely, for as long as *`exit`* allows *`ssh`* to carry-on proxying the *`null stream.`*

Also, have you checked to see if you've got a literal ***`$TMP`*** in your current working directory? I do see *`ENDSSH`* at the bottom which looks like a *`heredoc LIMITER`* to me so I believe either this is not the entire script or it has been edited by mistake. It would make sense if it were the body of a heredoc to use *`\$TMP,`* but as is I think *`nc`* will first *`>truncate`* then write its *`stdout`* to a file named ***`$TMP.`*** Then again, I guess you *`rm`* it anyway, so maybe you just didn't notice.

And because you're *`rm`ing **`$TMP`*** you may not have realized anyone would be asking this question:

How does *`$(mktemp)`* work for you without the *`filename.xxx`* argument?

**UPDATE** I looked closer at your output and definitely *`>/tmp/tmp.GJ1knZF5Jn`* means *`$(mktemp)`* is working - even the *`\$TMP`* part. So you've just taught me that I only need to specify *`mktemp .xxx`* if I specify a filename at all. Thank you.

Still I think there is a heredoc at the top somewhere? It could be there is not and *`\\`* is only an attempt to deal with a side-effect of the *`echo \$TMP <<<herestring,`* but I dunno... Interesting.

I don't know if I've got this completely right because I don't know where all of these variables come from. But, this is close to how I would do this:

*(which actually renders the last two questions irrelevant anyway)*

```
_ssh() ( ssh "$1"@"$2" 'printf %s, `cat` >> '"$3"
) <<-PARAMS   
    "$lastSourceIP" 
    "$lastDestinationIP" 
    "$sourceFqdn" 
    "$fqdn" 
    "$port" "
    "ConnectivityNA" 
    "NA" 
    "NA" 
    "Pas" 
    "$(date)"
PARAMS

nc -z -v -n $lastDestinationIP $port |\
    grep -q "succeeded" && suffix=txt
_ssh user host report.${suffix:-fail}
unset suffix
?ENDSSH?
```

***Note:*** the *`"$quotes"`* in the above are for *`printf's`* benefit on the other side of the *`ssh`* process - not for anything else. Those *`"quotes"`* remain as is even after all of the above *`PARAMS`* are evaluated.

There are some things going on up there that I've covered before. For instance the *`func() ( scope )`* I like to think was [covered ok here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/how-to-defer-variable-expansion/120142#120142). The *`${parameter:-expansion}`* was also covered there, but also demonstrated pretty well [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120475/how-can-i-pass-argument-stored-on-a-variable-to-wget/120487#120487). I've gotten into some of the weird heredoc stuff [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120528/how-to-define-similar-bash-function-at-once/120531#120531), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120736/parsing-process-command-line-arguments-in-unix/120817#120817), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22558545/2955202). Probably there are others - I guess I like messing up my shell or something.

In this case, though, using the function and the heredoc as I have, *`cat`* can't get stuck. *`PARAMS`* is sent over as *`stdin`* and *`cat`* will quit when it reaches an *`EOF` (or `CTRL-D`)* so as soon as it consumes *`PARAMS`* it's going to stop everytime. This is especially important if you are running this in a *`heredoc`* which is *also* on *`<&0`* because *`PARAMS`* will stand in the way of *`cat`* eating your script mid-execute.

Anyway, hopefully that helps. If I've missed anything, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks, I don't totally follow all this but wanted to mention that there is a weird difference between  "cat  | tee output.txt <<EOF" and "cat <<EOF | tee output.txt". Use the latter format in scripts because "cat | tee" can hang waiting for an Enter on stdin.